# Android cannot load images using Picasso

Tags: android, image, load, placeholder, picasso

I am using ListView which is made with Layout containing an ImageView and a TextView. Here is the code of my adapter

```
public class ResultsArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ImageText> implements Picasso.Listener {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = ResultsArrayAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    private Context mContext;
    private int mLayoutId;

    public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Image load fail: " + uri.toString() + ", message: " + exception.getMessage());
    }

    public ResultsArrayAdapter(Context context, int resourceId, int layoutId, List<ImageText> data) {
        super(context, resourceId, layoutId, data);
        mContext = context;
        mLayoutId = layoutId;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imageView;
        public TextView textView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        ImageText imageText = getItem(position);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(mLayoutId, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageview_result);
            viewHolder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview_result);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(mContext).build();
        picasso.load(imageText.getImageURL())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.artistplaceholder)
                .error(R.drawable.error).fit().into(viewHolder.imageView);
        viewHolder.textView.setText(imageText.getText());
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

ImageText contains two Strings, one for image url, and one for text. I am fetching data from spotify. I checked that imageText.getImageURL() returns actual image url, which opens a picture in my browser. Now the app fills the ListView with text, and places a placeholder on every entry. onImageLoadFailed doesn't get called. Here is link for Picasso library http://square.github.io/picasso/ . I am using version 2.3.3, which is compiled from gradle script with line compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.3'. The internet permission is added, the proof is the fact that I am able to fetch names.

Thanks for your help.

Maybe it also affects the result. Here is my layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/general_picture_side"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/general_picture_side"
        android:padding="@dimen/general_picture_padding"
        android:id="@+id/imageview_result"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/text_picture_offset"
        android:id="@+id/textview_result"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I didn't find anything suspicious till now. But try to initialize picasso only once in the adapter's life time (i.e. in the constructor) or use the static method `Picasso.with(context).load(...)` instead.

Comment: I did exactly this, then I found a post on stackoverflow which suggested to build first and then load with picasso.load(...)... Apparently it makes no difference

Comment: Maybe the images to be downloaded are large. Check this [discussion](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/370).

Comment: I just sudstituted imageText.getImageURL() with "http://screenshots.en.sftcdn.net/en/scrn/76000/76818/microsoft-small-basic-22.jpg" which is 100x100, still placeholders, and then I used "http://smallbeerpress.com/wp-content/uploads/itunes.png", this image is 50x50. Still placeholders

Comment: You're not setting the listener. Try `Picasso.Builder(mContext).listener(this).build()`.

Comment: onImageLoadFailed still is not called, and there are only placeholders

Comment: Do you see any warnings in the logcat?. And if there are any, post them.

Comment: here is an iteresting one 'Could not find method com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient.open, referenced from method com.squareup.okhttp.OkUrlFactory.open' , and just after this 'W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 13364: Lcom/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient;.open (Ljava/net/URL;Ljava/net/Proxy;)Ljava/net/HttpURLConnection;'

Comment: Try adding this gradle dependency `'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0-RC1'`.

Comment: it worked! I added okhttp-android-support module in gradle script.

Comment: Thank God. Always notice the warnings, and google them even as is. Searching "Could not find method com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient.open" got [this](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/763) where Picasso's author recommends the above solution.

Comment: Also post the solution as an answer with a brief description of the problem, and accept it for future visitors with the same problem.

Comment: I will, thank you. Actually I had okhttp-urlconnection, I googled okhttp, because I added this library not even visiting their site and repositories. On maven I found other modules, and I thought that android-support might be needed. The reason I added this library without android-support is that I added it for another java library which said it depended on okhttp, but said nothing about android (of course, it was java library). My mistake was adding okhttp without reviewing it first. And then ignoring logcat.